# What is the event called when application starts?

Tags: events

I am trying to attach a handler/code when the Sitecore web application instance is starting up.

What event is triggered when the application instance starts?

Comment: Can you expand on your question to make it clearer please? What do you mean by "instance" ?

Comment: Instance means Sitecore Web site Instance

Comment: Ok - so the application start is very different to a session start (from your question title) - which do you need?

Comment: application start I think is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok - for attaching code to when the application starts, you have a couple of options.

### Initialize Pipeline

The standard way to do this is via the `Initialize` pipeline. Create yourself a new processor class. It does not need to inherit from anything, but must have a public method called `Process` that takes a `PipelineArgs` object.

Example:

```
public class DoSomethingOnStartup
{
    public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        // Add your code here
    }
}
```

You would then patch that into Sitecore via an include file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="MyNamespace.DoSomethingOnStartup, MyAssembley" />
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

### WebActivatorEx

This is a slightly less Sitecorian way of doing it, but does work. Add [`WebActivatorEx`](https://github.com/davidebbo/WebActivator) to your project from NuGet.

Create your class and add it to the `App_Start` folder and add the `WebActivatorEx` attribute:

Example:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(TestWebApp.TestStartupCode.MyStartupCode), "Start",Order = 1)]

namespace TestWebApp.TestStartupCode
{
    public static class MyStartupCode
    {
        public static bool StartCalled { get; set; }

        public static void Start()
        {
            StartCalled = true;
            Debug.WriteLine("MyStartUpCode1");
        }
    }
}
```

### Which to use?

It really is up to your requirements, both methods work. Using the Sitecore pipeline, means you can get access to other data in the Sitecore initialize pipeline and also you can position your startup code to run at a specific point in the start up. Its the option I would take 95% of the time.

If for some reason you can't or don't want to rely on the Sitecore pipeline, `WebActivator` is a good alternative. E.g if you are writing a component and don't have access to modify any configuration.

### What about the Global.asax

Historically, this was also an option, but as this has now been made private by Sitecore, it is not a viable option anymore.

Answer (score -4):

Create your own `Global.asax` codebehind inheriting the sitecore one.

There you can put an event handler for the `Application_Start` event to execute your custom code.

Comment: Don't do this anymore - it will not work with later versions of Sitecore.

Comment: Yes. Do not change OOTB Sitecore files unless absolutely necessary. The best practices and recommended answer to this is Richard's - using the Initialize Pipeline - that is exactly what it is for.

Comment: The class Sitecore.Web.Application that the default Global.asax file uses has a virtual method for Application_Start, so yes, you can override it and it will work - I got the 8.2 update-4 version and I'm doing this. I totally agree not to mess with OOTB sitecore files but it's the Global.asax file that we're talking about. It would be dumb of Sitecore to completely own this file and not let developers extend it for their own implementation.

Comment: If you are worried about upgrade paths, I urge against this approach. Even on older versions it was a pain going between versions where the way Sitecore was using Global.asax was changing underneath you. It makes life easier long term to avoid this pain.